# jquery document on hover function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering a function that will work similar like:

```
$(document).click(function () {});
```

but with hover function.
When I tried with :

```
$(document).hover(function () {});
```

its not working.Can any body give me some idea about this problem.
i.e.My main aim is when user mouse hover on body or documents any will give an alert message..

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#YourElementId').hover(function(){
     alert('mouse hovered'); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take care of including **jQuery** in your page. Then, you can do

```
$('.someclass').on('hover', function(){ alert("something"); });
```

or

```
  $('.someclass').hover(function(){ alert("something"); });
```

try to avoid to `bind` `hover` to `document` unless you have to `delegate` an `event` so you should do

```
$(document).on('hover', '.someclass', function() {});
```

Binding `hover` to `document` can provide bad experience to your users, specifically if you are showing alerts, unless, as always, you take care of which element have to show it.